# How to add a search engine feature in an Android application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, search-engine

I need to create a search engine feature for my application. It should search particular websites. Is there any way to develop this in Android. **[image: api]**

I need to add this as a feature in my Android application.

Answer (score 0):

initialize in your activity edittext for me is it address_search_view

```
addresses_search_view.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   Addresses.this.addressesSAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);}
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   }
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }
});
```

Comment: Here how to specify particular websites like custom search engine? also i want to do some mining in it